# Unable to get currentTime proprty from react h5 audio player in react

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, audio-player

I want to show current time property of react h5 audio player in react html. I tried to use useeffect with dependency  but it is still not updating time with new value. please see below code and attached sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/list-keepr-app-forked-vhzkyr

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import AudioPlayer from "react-h5-audio-player";
import "react-h5-audio-player/lib/styles.css";
import Button from "./components/Button";

export default function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [playTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const inputFileRef = useRef(null);
  const audioRef = useRef(null);
  function clickHandle(e) {
    console.log(inputFileRef.current.files[0]);

    const filename = URL.createObjectURL(inputFileRef.current.files[0]);

    setFile(filename);
    // console.log();
  }

 
  function handleTimeUpdate() {
    setCurrentTime(audioRef.current.audio.current.currentTime);
  }
  //console.log(audioRef.current.audio.current.currentTime);
  useEffect(()=>{

    handleTimeUpdate()
    
  },[playTime])
  
  
  return (
    <div>
     
      
      <Button refs={inputFileRef} clickHandle={clickHandle}/>
      <p>Current time: {playTime}</p>
      <AudioPlayer
        autoPlay
        src={file}
        onPlay={(e) => console.log("playing")}
        ref={audioRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: @Jash1395   bro please review question.you may solve my problem.thanks

Comment: I am able to get time with setInterval function but  still it does not look like optimal solution. please review codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/list-keeper-with-timing-forked-0zdwbh